# scrapy strategy with links with names

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to find the best strategy to read links with names (eg. href=/mypage#sectionA )
If I don't do anything special, this kind of link can get skipped if I've already visited that page. If I check if my url has a hash (#), I can parse the result before yielding a new request, but it works only if the link point to a name on the same page.
How should I manage this kind of link? Disable duplicate check and potentially parse a page many many times?

Comment: Just do `Request(dont_filter=True)` so scrapy will not filter duplicate links.

Comment: @Umair I'd prefer not to request the same page several times. Isn't there a better solution?

Comment: Your question is very unclear .. what do you want? you are asking how to avoid duplicate requests like `mypage#sectionA`  and `mypage#sectionB`

Comment: @Umair I am facing a problem many people probably had and wanted to know if there an easy solution to develop, both for code readability and speed (that is, less crawling). Consider that I'm reading categories from a site where sometimes the same category appears on many parent categories.